# How to wrap everything inside a Input type of sgqlc operation

Tags: python, graphql

I have the sampe code like this

```
from sgqlc.types import *


class Input(Input):
    a = bool
    b = bool


class Nodes(Type):
    point = float
    description = str


class Query(Type):
    point = Field(Nodes, args={'vehicle':Input})

query = Operation(Query)

query.point(vehicle={'a':False,'b':True})

print(query)
```

Output:

```
query {
  point(vehicle: {a: false, b: true}) {
    point
    description
  }
}
```

In my case, is it possible to remove the fields vehicle, I want the query become like this:

Expected output

```
query {
  point(a: false, b: true) {
    point
    description
  }
}
```

I understand that it is easy if we do that

```
class Query(Type):
    point = Field(Nodes, args={'a':bool, 'b': bool})
```

But, in my case, I want to everything needs to be wrapped inside a Input type:

```
class Query(Type):
    point = Field(Nodes, args={'vehicle':Input})
```

Is there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can using [graphql-query](https://github.com/denisart/graphql-query) for this:

```py
from graphql_query import Argument, Operation, Query

vehicle = Argument(
    name="vehicle",
    value=[
        Argument(name="a", value="false"),
        Argument(name="b", value="true"),
    ]
)

point = Query(
    name="point",
    fields=["point", "description"],
    arguments=[vehicle]
)

operation = Operation(
    type="query",
    queries=[point]
)

print(operation.render())
"""
query {
  point(
    vehicle: {
      a: false
      b: true
    }
  ) {
    point
    description
  }
}
"""
```

and

```py
from graphql_query import Argument, Operation, Query


point = Query(
    name="point",
    fields=["point", "description"],
    arguments=[
        Argument(name="a", value="false"),
        Argument(name="b", value="true"),
    ]
)

operation = Operation(
    type="query",
    queries=[point]
)

print(operation.render())
"""
query {
  point(
    a: false
    b: true
  ) {
    point
    description
  }
}
"""
```

Comment: Full documentation can be found at https://denisart.github.io/graphql-query/